# using Ethereum private key to encrypt string

Tags: ethereum

I need to encrypt a string using the private key of my ethereum account on an Ethereum private network.

How can I do this using web3js?

**Note**: The Ethereum client I use is Geth.

Answer (score 0):

You may find your answer here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3092/how-to-encrypt-a-message-with-the-public-key-of-an-ethereum-address

With geth on its own I don't think that it is possible, however with [bitcore-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-lib) and [bitcore-ecies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bitcore-ecies) it is.